# Hyper-V Synthetic Ethernet Port: Error 'Access is denied'

Tags: ethernet, hyper-v, port, switch

Any suggestion how I can fix it without resetting Windows?

**The error I get on VM start up**
[image: The error I get on VM start up]

I have tried everything basic like switching off and on Hyper-V, deleting and recreating virtual switches, using external and internal ones, resetting network adapters and some other tricks I have found on the Internet but nothing helps. I have also tried with clean boot disabling all non-Microsoft services in msconfig. VM starts if no virtual switch is selected.

Just to note, I have another PC with basically the same Windows (cloned by Acronis) and everything is good there!

Comment: See if this Microsoft post helps:   ....    https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/41daddd9-b2ad-4ec2-ab83-0b72858f15ce/error-with-synthetic-ethernet-port?forum=winserverhyperv

Comment: I have only microsoft defender and I have already added the hyper-v folder to the exclusions and tried to deacitvate it - no luck. I have also did Windows 11 upgrade in place and it still didn't fix the issue. Gosh, I just can't afford a fresh install. Any ideas about registry tweak maybe?